# Vamos: colocar os pingos nos "ii", nos "iis", nos "is", ou nos "i's"? Entre aspas ou não?

Tags: ortografia

Já vi a frase escrita de diversas formas: vamos por os pingos [**nos is**](http://www.qualeagiria.com.br/giria/colocar-os-pingos-nos-is/), [**nos ii**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=w1q_0hAckwYC&pg=PA118&dq=%22%22Vamos+colocar+os+pingos+nos+ii%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-y42oy6PQAhXSqZAKHYQYADo4FBDoAQhHMAg#v=onepage&q=%22%22Vamos%20colocar%20os%20pingos%20nos%20ii%22&f=false), [**nos iis**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=RxVlDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA42&dq=%22%22Vamos+colocar+os+pingos+nos+ii%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHiqf6yqPQAhVJHJAKHZDgAQUQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22%22Vamos%20colocar%20os%20pingos%20nos%20ii%22&f=false), [**nos i's**](https://mansueto.wordpress.com/2014/08/28/os-pingos-nos-is/) e também entre aspas, [**nos "is"**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=uUA5BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA523&dq=%22%22Vamos+colocar+os+pingos+nos+i%27s%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGz9rmy6PQAhVJUZAKHaX4CQYQ6AEIJTAC#v=onepage&q=%22%22Vamos%20colocar%20os%20pingos%20nos%20i's%22&f=false). Qual seria a forma correta?  Com ou sem aspas?

Comment: Os _pingos_ nos is? Para os meus lados só ouço "_pontos_ nos is", mas a pergunta acaba por ser aplicável aos dois casos.

Comment: @E_net4   Cá, do lado ocidental do Atlântico, dizemos "os pingos nos ii" ou "is" ou qualquer outra forma.  E, "por os pingos nos is" é idiomático.

Comment: Bem sei que é idiomático, estou a acrescentar que existe "pôr os pontos nos is" em Portugal.

Comment: Eu digo pingos nos is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O plural do substantivo ***i*** é ***ii*** ou ***is***, sem aspas nem apóstrofes.  Isto é aliás válido para as outras letras: admitem um plural regular, *ás, bês, cês, efes agás*; e um plural gráfico, *aa, bb, cc*, etc.; o plural de *xis* é *xx* ou *xis* (e não xises), constituindo assim uma meia exceção. Estes duplos plurais vêm no [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/i), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=i), Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) e dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (Lisboa, 2001). Este último traz também a versão lusitana da expressão com os dois plurais:

> **i** ou **I** [í]. *s. m.* (Do latim *i* ou *I*). **1** nona letra e terceira vogal do alfabeto português   [...] **pôr os pontos nos ii/is**, deixar a situação bem clara, sem margem para equívocos. Pl. ii ou is.

Os outros dicionários optam por apresentar a expressão com um ou o outro plural. O [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=pingo), [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/pingo) e Houaiss (verbete *pingo*) optam por *is*: «pôr os pingos nos is»; o [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/ponto), por *ii*: «pôr os pontos nos ii»; e a Infopédia, para não ofender ninguém, por [*ii* no verbete *ponto*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ponto) e [*is* no verbete *i*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/i).

Aspas não fazem aqui qualquer sentido. As aspas não fazem parte das palavras; simplesmente servem para indicar um uso especial, como uma citação, um uso irónico (*prefiro passar sem a “ajuda” dele*), um termo inusitado na linguagem do locutor (*meu amigo português está embevecido com seu “puto”*) ou um estrangeirismo ou neologismo ainda não consagrado na língua. Talvez algumas pessoas sejam tentadas a pôr *ii* ou *is* entre aspas precisamente por pensarem que não são palavras consagradas.

O apóstrofe também não faz sentido. Possivelmente é influência do seu uso (criticado, ver [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not)) no plural de acrónimos em inglês.