# Plural de abreviações ou siglas em português com letras duplas (dobradas)

Tags: ortografia, número-gramatical, abreviações

O português há alguns anos (centenas ?) já teve o plural de siglas ou abreviações similar ao espanhol, dobrando letras na abreviação, exemplo Estados Unidos: EEUU (ou EE.UU.)

Seria um erro ou uma afronta às regras ortográficas atuais abreviar palavras com essa regra ? Ou só é permitido as abreviações atuais documentadas? E quais as condições para a reprodução de textos antigos ?

**MAIS INFORMAÇÕES E EXEMPLOS:**

Há também organizações ou sociedades, como a Maçonaria, que mesmo em Português, utilizam desta regra dobrando as letras quando é um plural abreviado, e profissionais que convivem com textos antigos lidam também com abreviações nesta forma, muitas vezes preservando o original replicando a forma de como eram escritas - profissionais da área de direito com mais frequência.

De uma foma ou de outra há resquícios dessa prática (ou regra). Há textos na internet documentando a abreviação do plural de algumas palavras onde se dobram as letras, exemplo:

- Vossas Majestades: VV.MM.
- Autores: AA.
- Vossas Altezas: VV.AA.

Há regras também para o plural de letras, como exemplo as vogais no plural teriam um s ao final ou são dobradas ?

- Múltiplos as: Múltiplos aa
- Múltiplos is: Múltiplos ii.
- etc

---

Algumas fontes:

- http://pucrs.br/manualred/tratamento.php
- https://www.significados.com.br/eeuu/
- http://letratura.blogspot.com.br/2009/08/plural-das-letras.html
- http://www.crescabrasil.com.br/pessoas/347/material/Abreviaturas.pdf

Comment: Eu via em vários textos EEUU e não entendia o porquê!

Comment: Para os plurais das letras vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3851/vamos-colocar-os-pingos-nos-ii-nos-iis-nos-is-ou-nos-is-entre-aspa/3854#3854) : podes dobrar a letra ou acrescentar *s* ao nome da letra.

Comment: @Peixoto  Você pode compartilhar esses textos ? Já vi alguns casos que parecem misturar Espanhol com Português, pode ser uma tradução do Espanhol pro Português sem alguns cuidados.

Comment: [“No entanto, em português, há outras palavras e expressões no plural que têm abreviaturas com letras dobradas; p.ex., *AA.,* abreviatura de «autores».”](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/repeticao-de-letras-em-siglas-e-abreviaturas/26389) Mas também: [“Em espanhol, quando queremos abreviar palavras e expressões no plural, usamos letras dobradas.”](http://www.guiapraticodeespanhol.com.br/2009/10/uso-de-las-abreviaturas-eeuu-y-jj-oo.html)

Comment: [“Em alguns casos, as letras maiúsculas são dobradas: AA. (autores). Às vezes, as letras maiúsculas dobradas representam superlativos: DD. (Digníssimo).”](https://books.google.com/books?id=frmkvNpZJikC&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=letras+dobradas+em+abreviações&source=bl&ots=wsrbaTBACT&sig=9QXNeDYe5WOQbKVdl1yUEAIyo4E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi53NS4wJDUAhUFSCYKHb9GCSAQ6AEITTAF#v=onepage&q=letras%20dobradas%20em%20abreviações&f=false)

Comment: Luciano, *DD* é *digníssimo*, e [*MM* (Priberam)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/MM) é *meritíssimo;* são singulares, não são plurais, como indica o [crescabrasil](http://www.crescabrasil.com.br/pessoas/347/material/Abreviaturas.pdf) linkado na pergunta.

Comment: @jacinto Tinha visto isso, mas jurava que tinha encontrado divergências com outra fonte. Bem se eu achá-la adiciono às referências, por ora os removi dos exemplos.

Comment: Mais um exemplo, do IBGE: uma RN (referência de nível), muitas RRNN (referências de nível). Eu particularmente acho essa pluralização arcaica e venho utilizando "RNs". https://ww2.ibge.gov.br/home/geociencias/geodesia/altimetrica.shtm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A pluralização de abreviações por duplicação das letras é aconselhável apenas nos casos já consagrados, como *VV.MM.* ‘Vossas Majestades’, *SS.MM.* Suas Majestades, *VV.AA.* ‘Vossas Altezas’, etc. O que muitos gramáticos recomendam e o uso vem consagrando é a formação do plural pela adição de um *s* minúsculo: *uma ONG, duas ONGs* (‘organização não governamental’). Por exemplo, [este artigo no Gramaticalhas](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI124907,61044-Siglas+CNDS+ou+CNDs) cita quatro gramáticos que aprovam a formação do plural de siglas com *s*. É essa também a recomendação no [Manual de Redação da Folha de São Paulo](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/folha/circulo/manual_texto_s.htm) e no [Manual de Comunicação do Senado Federal do Brasil)](https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/redacao-e-estilo/estilo/siglas). A única posição discordante que encontrei ([Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/siglas-no-plural/15596) e [*Dúvida Linguística* no FliP](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1570)) recomenda manter a sigla invariável: *uma ONG, duas ONG*.

Agora, tudo isto são apenas recomendações. Como diz Cláudio Moreno [(“Plural das Siglas”,*Sua Língua*)](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/14/plural-das-siglas/), que também aprova o plural com *s*, “não há um deus da gramática”, e o Acordo Ortográfico em vigor nada diz sobre o assunto. Por isso não podemos dizer que o plural por duplicação de letras fora dos poucos casos consagrados seja um erro ou uma afronta às regras ortográficas atuais; mas vai com certeza contra a prática corrente. E cada um dirá qual das seguintes formas melhor favorece a comunicação (“notícia” inventada):

> Várias OO.NN.GG. pediram à C.P.L.P. (Comunidade dos Países de Língua Portuguesa) que melhorasse o seu site. Mas parece haver duas CC.PP.LL.PP, uma interessado em progredir, outra em protelar.
>
> Várias ONGs pediram à CPLP (Comunidade dos Países de Língua Portuguesa) que melhorasse o seu site. Mas parece haver duas CPLPs, uma interessado em progredir, outra em protelar.
>
> Várias ONG pediram à CPLP (Comunidade dos Países de Língua Portuguesa) que melhorasse o seu site. Mas parece haver duas CPLP, uma interessada em progredir, outra em protelar.

Eu prefiro a versão com *s*, que é aliás a que vem ganhando consenso. A versão com letras dobradas deixaria muitos leitores a coçar a cabeça.

Um argumento a favor do *s* é que nós tendemos a tratar as siglas, mesmo aquelas pronunciadas por soletração (como *CD*, que é lido como *cê-dê*, ao contrário de *ONU*), como uma palavra, e é por isso natural acrescentar um *s*, para formar o plural, lendo-se *um cê-dê, dois cê-dês* [(ver artigo do Cláudio Moreno)](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/14/plural-das-siglas/). Isto é válido, naturalmente, apenas para siglas que designam entidades singulares que podem ser pluralizadas: *uma ONG, duas ONGs*. Algumas siglas já são gramaticalmente plurais, como *os EUA,* não havendo necessidade de indicar o número plural com *s* ou dobragem de letras. Encontrei de facto alguns exemplos de *EE.UU.* em textos do século XIX, mas não vejo nessa sigla qualquer mérito. Mas eu diria, “existem dois EUAs [*e-u-ás*], um urbano, outro rural”.

Quanto à citação de textos antigos, é perfeitamente legítimo reproduzi-los fielmente, juntando notas explicativas se necessário. É aliás boa prática em qualquer texto indicar por extenso o significado da sigla, exceto as sobejamente conhecidas, na primeira vez que ela aparece no texto. Depois, em domínios específicos pode haver normas ou tradições próprias. O plural das siglas não está regulamentado; a explosão de siglas é uma coisa relativamente recente na história da língua, e o consenso está ainda em formação. Portanto é uma questão de bom-senso e ver o que favorece a comunicação.

Onde há consenso é que não se usa apóstrofo: *ONGs*, tudo bem, mas não **ONG’s.* Este uso do apóstrofo é provavelmente influência do inglês, mas mesmo aí ele é desaconselhado salvo raras exceções [(ELU.SE)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not). No passado indicava-se a parte de cada palavra numa sigla com um ponto (*E.U.A., O.N.U*), mas a tendência atual é para evitar esse “entulho gráfico” ([*Veja*](http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/plural-de-siglas-ha-contradicao-entre-os-pms-e-os-eua/), manuais da [Folha](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/folha/circulo/manual_texto_s.htm) e do [Senado](https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/redacao-e-estilo/estilo/siglas)). No entanto, os pontos são usados nos plurais com letras dobradas. Por razões históricas—esses plurais são heranças do passado—e ajudam-nos a saber que cada duas letras representa uma só palavra, por exemplo: *SS.MM.* é ‘Suas Majestades’ e não, por exemplo, ‘sem sal é muito melhor’.

O plural das letras pode formar-se por duplicação ou acrescentando um *s* ao nome da letra: *aa* ou *ás, bb* ou *bês, ff* ou *efes, hh* ou *agás,* etc., como explicado na resposta a [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3851/vamos-colocar-os-pingos-nos-ii-nos-iis-nos-is-ou-nos-is-entre-aspa/3854#3854). Isto é no entanto uma questão diferente: por exemplo, *vv* referem várias letras *v*, como em, “há três *vv* em *vavavá*”; em *VV.MM* os dois *vv* referem a palavra *vossas*, não referem letras.

Comment: Só um adendo: no Brasil (não sei se em todas as regiões) a pronúncia de ONG é *ôngui*, e o respectivo plural é *ônguis*. Mas pelo jeito não há uma regra geral para a pronúncia de siglas. A Agência Nacional de Saúde (ANS), que poderia ser pronunciada exatamente como *âns*, acaba sendo soletrada (*a-ene-esse*). Já a Faculdade de Filosofia, Letras e Ciências Humanas (FFLCH), que deveria ser soletrada, acaba sendo transformada em palavra (*fefeléchi*).

Comment: @Hugo, não sabia disso. Vou incluir o exemplo da ANS então. O argumento para a adição do *s* é válido de qualquer modo.

Comment: Agora surgiu uma dúvida: se a sigla termina em S, como ficaria o plural? Com um s minúsculo depois do S?

Comment: @Hugo, Sim, as SSs (lol, *esse-esses*) dos países envelhecidos correm risco de falência. Bem imagino que CD seja cê-dê em todo o lado.

Comment: @Hugo: Não tenho dados estatísticos, apenas conversando e conhecendo culturas, notei que no nordeste do Brasil, em especial na Bahia, há tendência a pronunciar siglas como palavras inteiras, o caso da Fefeleche (FFLCH), seria um exemplo - apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Eu entendo o ciberduvidas pois o artigo ou outro termo que antecede a sigla já definirá o plural, e assim evita-se alterar as siglas por acréscimos que não fazem parte delas. Além disso, a sigla já pode significar uma palavra no plural, como AA - Alcoólicos Anônimos.

Comment: @André, eu também entendo, até certo ponto. Mas eu sou mais sensível ao argumento a favor do *s*: que na nossa língua a tendência natural é acrescentar um *s* para passar do singular para o plural.

Comment: @Jacinto como você transcreveria um texto antigo com um plural de abreviação em letras dobradas ? Claro que depende do texto e o público alvo, mas você teria uma tendência a transcrever e adicionar uma nota de rodapé ou adaptaria a transcrição e adicionaria a nota para explicar que o texto tinha um escrita não usual para a atualidade ?

Comment: Há várias possibilidades. A minha tendência, que é uma preferência pessoal, é citar tal e qual; se necessário, em vez de nota de rodapé, punha o significado entre colchetes: "os AA. [autores] opinam..."; colchetes são uma forma consagrada de incluir elementos extra numa citação. Mas também é legítimo atualizar ou desenvolver abreviaturas. Por exemplo, quando cito o Houaiss frequentemente passo a extenso, para melhor legibilidade, várias abreviações, incluindo uma nota, normalmente entre parênteses antes da citação.