# Quando usar pontos em siglas?

Tags: pontuação, siglas

Vou usar como exemplo o Instituto Nacional do Seguro Social, que é encurtado para "INSS" na maioria das vezes.

A grafia correta seria "INSS" ou "I.N.S.S."? Ou tanto faz?

E para outras palavras fora esse exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma das regras é que quando a sigla forma uma outra palavra ou ela é lida como uma nova palavra não há ponto de separação. Cito como exemplo, **Petrobras**, **ARENA** (Aliança Renovadora Nacional, antigo partido político dos tempos da ditadura de 1964).

Por outro lado, quando lemos letra por letra, não há uma regra clara. No teu exemplo, I.N.S.S., teria que ter ponto segundo o site [Gramaticalhas](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI16285,91041-CPI+ou+CPI). Porém, no próprio site, diz que estamos entrando em desuso dos pontos de forma geral.

> 1) Quando a abreviatura das palavras se dá pela utilização de suas
>   iniciais, tem-se uma sigla. Exs.: DASP (Departamento Administrativo do
>   Serviço Público), I.N.S.S. (Instituto Nacional de Seguridade Social).
>
> 2) A questão do regime das abreviaturas e, por conseguinte, das
>   siglas, não é pacífica, mas algumas ponderações podem ser feitas com
>   proveito.
>
> 3) Uma primeira observação é que, nas siglas, o mais lógico é não usar
>   o ponto de separação, se as letras são pronunciadas formando nova
>   palavra, como ARENA (Aliança Renovadora Nacional, antigo partido
>   político dos tempos da ditadura de 1964); se, todavia, a leitura da
>   sigla se dá em soletração, então o mais adequado é usar o ponto de
>   separação entre as letras, como em F.N.M. (Fábrica Nacional de
>   Motores).
>
> 4) Essa, aliás, é a lição de Cândido de Oliveira: “se lermos letra por
>   letra (ene, ge, bê), entre elas há ponto (N.G.B.); se as letras formam
>   um todo significativo, não há ponto: DEA”.
>
> 5) Do primeiro caso, para o mesmo autor, são exemplos I.N.S.S.
>   (Instituto Nacional de Seguridade Social) e P.V.O.L.P. (Pequeno
>   Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa), enquanto do segundo são
>   MEC (Ministério da Educação e Cultura), PETROBRAS (Petróleo
>   Brasileiro), SESI (Serviço Social da Indústria) e UBE (União
>   Brasileira de Escritores). 1
>
> 6) Apesar da lição tradicional anterior, Luciano Correia da Silva
>   anota que o uso constante vem contrariando a regra segundo a qual se
>   utilizam pontos nas siglas cujas letras se pronunciam separadamente:
>   de I.N.P.S., O.A.B., segundo tal autor, passou-se, na prática, a
>   escrever INPS e OAB.
>
> 7) Em outra passagem, acrescenta tal autor que “há uma tendência
>   crescente para a eliminação dos pontos nas siglas em geral: MP
>   (Ministério Público), CPC (Código de Processo Civil), TJ (Tribunal de
>   Justiça), RT (Revista dos Tribunais), STF (Supremo Tribunal Federal),
>   STJ (Superior Tribunal de Justiça), CLT (Consolidação das Leis do
>   Trabalho), MP (Medida Provisória), PM (Polícia Militar).2
>
> 8) Em mesmo sentido, para Regina Toledo Damião e Antonio Henriques, as
>   siglas, em casos dessa natureza, podem vir, indiferentemente,
>   acompanhadas ou não de ponto – MEC ou M.E.C., CIC ou C.I.C. –
>   acrescentando tais autores que “a tendência moderna é o uso de siglas
>   sem pontuação”.3
>
> 9) Com todas essas observações e posições divergentes dos nossos
>   autores, vê-se que tanto se pode escrever CPI como C.P.I. Todavia se
>   deve anotar que a tendência à simplificação faz com que mais e mais se
>   dê preferência à primeira grafia. Repita-se, porém, que ambas as
>   formas estão corretas.

Dessa forma, procurei artigos mais atulizados e encontrei uma explicação no [infoenem - P.S.: Como Escrever Corretamente Siglas e Abreviaturas](https://www.infoenem.com.br/p-s-como-escrever-corretamente-siglas-e-abreviaturas-2/). Nesse site, há uma explicação bem parecida, mas simplesmente não mais utlizando pontos entre as letras.

Assim, concluo que os dois modos estão corretos, quando lido letra por letra. Porém já em desuso utlizar pontos para separar cada letra.

Comment: Sim, foi também essa a ideia que eu apanhei quando respondi a [esta pergunta sobre o plural das siglas](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4511/plural-de-abrevia%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ou-siglas-em-portugu%C3%AAs-com-letras-duplas-dobradas): que o uso do ponto nas siglas tem vindo a diminuir. Houve quem lhe chamasse "entulho gráfico". Por exemplo os manuais da Folha de São Paulo e do Senado Federal do Brasil recomendam a sigla sem pontos.